# What's the secret behind super durability of latest ADW Launcher EX?

Tags: adw-launcher-ex

Update of ADW Launcher EX is back again after a long time. It brings lot of visual tweaks as well as performance boosts. After few days of experience, I have encountered one even more interesting thing: I am unable to kill it by increasing system load (which is a very good thing).

When foreground apps are launched, Android kills background apps based on `minfree` values. The apps having running services and notification get higher priority than normal background apps, but get lesser priority than foreground apps.

Latest version of ADW Launcher EX has a running service (but no higher priority running notification) which is same as old versions and other launcher apps. I have used Go Launcher EX, LauncherPro, old version of ADW Launcher EX etc. All get killed when heavy foreground apps are launched, but latest version of ADW Launcher EX isn't getting killed. Instead, foreground apps are being killed when system load is high.

Previously, hot reboot was also able to kill ADW Launcher EX, but now even that one fails.

What's the magic behind all these? I am just curious...

Comment: You mean the oom_adj value? As described in [Taming the OOM killer](http://lwn.net/Articles/317814/)?

Comment: @Izzy No. `oom_adj` can't be the case because ADW Launcher EX doesn't request root privilege at all.

Comment: It would be interesting that you say what version of Android you run, because the task management policies can vary a lot on that front

Comment: @rds Same experience on GB & ICS both..

Comment: The question is no longer valid for latest version of ADW Launcher EX..

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about a problem to be solved.

Answer (score -1):

Apps can obtain higher privileges. For example 3G watchdog (a data usage monitoring app) requests users for higher privileges so that it cannot be killed. It may be the same case with ADW launcher.

Comment: Does it require root to set the thread of said app to a higher privilege?